# How to download Image from browser & upload to Amazon S3

Tags: javascript, image, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, download

How can I allow the client to upload an image in the browser, and then I upload it to Amazon S3?  I have been looking around a lot and have found no resources explaining how to do this.

Are there any tutorials that I could follow?

Are there any libraries that I should use for this?

I am using AngularJS on the frontend and Node.js on the backend.

Comment: So you googled "nodejs file upload" and found nothing...? Hard to believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, look for two different tutorials. One for uploading from a client to a server, one for uploading from a server to S3.

StackOverflow discourages linking to specific tutorials, but there are lots of them out there, so it shouldn't be too tricky to track down.

For the client-to-server, you'll want to do a basic HTML form upload up to the server, then snag the data. You can temporarily write it to your file system (if you're on Linux, the `/tmp` directory is a good place to stash it).

After that, just upload from your server to S3. Amazon itself has some good documentation on that. The `s3` package for Node also has good examples: https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3

It's also possible to go straight from the browser to S3, which may be better depending on your use case. Check this out: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need the [AWS SDK for node](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/). Then they have a pretty comprehensive [developper guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/welcome.html). You may have to read up on credential management, too.

the procedure would be as follows

1. user uploads the image from browser to your server (I'd recomend [plain form upload](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_uploadfiles.asp), unless you feel ok with [uploading via ajax](https://coligo.io/building-ajax-file-uploader-with-node/))
2. then your server [uses the SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadingObjects.html) to save to S3
3. you display back info to the user (link to the image, upload status ?).

you could also use [pre-signed posts](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html) but that seems more advanced and I haven't seen info on it for Node.